# Uiwebview on uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Is it possible to have a uiwebview on uiscrollview? I am facing an issue that if I use a webview on a regular view controller I can able to load the html content but if I do the same when the webview is on scroll view then I'm not able to load the html content. For loading the html content I'm using loadhtmlstring. Please guide me. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code... it could be something their. A Scroll view should be able to accommodate any view. You are probably adding them in the wrong order or forgetting to add something.

Comment: If you are doing it in interface builder make sure you are connecting the Xib file correctly